# Inclusion/Exclusion Counting

Tags: combinatorics

At a particular school, all students participate in at least one out of three activities: debate, music, and community service. 3 students do all three activities, 21 students do two or more activities, half of all students participate in music, and the ratio of participants in debate, music, and community service, respectively, is $5:4:3$. What is the total number of students at the school?

So I gave Debate 5x people, music 4x people, and community service 3x people. So the total number of people is $5x+4x+3x-21+3= 12x-18$. Now music is half of the total, or $6x-9$. But this is equal to $4x$, so we have $6x-9=4x$. But then x is not a whole number! Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Look at the phrase "$21$ students do two or more activities" a bit more closely and how that should relate to inclusion-exclusion.  Remember that $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$

Comment: In case that comment was not explicit enough, you incorrectly assumed that $|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|$ in the above was equal to $21$.

Comment: Ok, so I need to add 3 twice to 21 to get 27 for A∩B|+|A∩C|+|B∩C|?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of students involved in two or more clubs is

$$21=|(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)|$$

Applying inclusion-exclusion to *this* gives us...

> $$=|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap A\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap B\cap C|-|A\cap C\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap A\cap C\cap B\cap C|$$

$~$

> $$=|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

And so $|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|$ is equal to

> $21+6=27$

Using this new corrected value in the inclusion-exclusion expansion in your original attempt:

> $5x+4x+3x-27+3=12x-24$

And so...

Comment: And so 6x-12 = 4x, x = 6, and the total number of students is 48.